# How to order Django queryset by an attribute of the parent model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Profile model that extends the Django User model,

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=True)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    activity_level = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, null=True, blank=True)
    tdee = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_username()
```

and when I try to access the queryset:

```
queryset = Profile.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
```

it says

```
FieldError at /users/
Cannot resolve keyword 'date_joined' into field. Choices are: activity_level, height, id, set, sex, tdee, user, user_id, weight
```

How do I order my queryset by the attribute from the parent model of the Profile class, which in this case is the User model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not inheriting the `django.contrib.auth` user model, as we can see, you are doing a OneToOne relationship with the `django.contrib.auth` user model. So the `django.contrib.auth` user model are not going to be in your `Profile` model. 
You are probably going to solve this like this:

```
queryset = Profile.objects.all().order_by('-user__date_joined')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!